# how can it be possible getting the same string from different bytes data in java?

Tags: java, utf-8, byte

I found out a strange problem in converting bytes to UTF8 string in Java.
Why bytes1 and bytes2 are different, but str1 and srt2 is the same?

Here is test code.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes1 = Hex.decodeHex("EDA0BDEDB88A".toCharArray());
        byte[] bytes2 = Hex.decodeHex("F09F988A".toCharArray());

        System.out.println("bytes1 length: " + bytes1.length);
        System.out.println("bytes2 length: " + bytes2.length);

        String str1 = new String(bytes1, "utf8");
        String str2 = new String(bytes2, "utf8");

        System.out.println("str1 is equals str2? " + str1.equals(str2));
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the test code running on jdk7

```
bytes1 length: 6
bytes2 length: 4
str1 is equals str2? true
```

Is it possible to find out the relationship between 'EDA0BDEDB88A' and 'F09F988A'?

'F09F988A' is a [unicode smail face](http://www.charbase.com/1F60A-unicode-loudly-crying-face), but 'EDA0BDEDB88A' is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Both byte sequences F09F988A and EDA0BDEDB88A are decoded by Java to the same codepoint U+1F60A (SMILING FACE WITH SMILING EYES).

Even if the encoding EDA0BDEDB88A is incorrect, it is accepted by the Java UTF-8 implementation as separate UTF-8 encoding of each of the surrogate code points U+D83D and U+DE0A. This representation is however strictly speaking not allowed in UTF-8, but e.g. defined in CESU-8 ( Compatibility Encoding Scheme for UTF-16).